# Limitation of entities to insert Azure Table Storage

Tags: python, azure, azure-table-storage

https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/azure/storage/tables/table-storage-design

According to the above website, Maximum request rate per storage account seems to be 20000 entities, but is 20000 entities per second the maximum even when inserting entity into table storage?

If 20000 entities is the maximum, does it mean that this limit cannot be exceeded even if parallelization is performed?

**Postscripts**

Thank you for all of your answer. I have one more question.

Does a transaction mean an operation on table storage? If so, does it mean that if the operation to insert 100 entities using batch processing is done at 20,000 transactions per second, then effectively 2000000 entities can be inserted per second?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you're right.

But if you want to increase the maximum value beyond 20000, please [contact the azure support](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/faq/#enterprise).

Here is the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/scalability-targets-standard-account#scale-targets-for-standard-storage-accounts) describes the limitation and suggest you increasing the maximum value if you need more. Also attach an screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's 20,000 transactions per second **per storage account** so no, you can't get over that limit using parallelization.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/scalability-targets-standard-account

Comment: Thank you for your response.
Does a transaction mean an operation on table storage?
If so, does it mean that if the operation to insert 100 entities is done at 20,000 transactions per second, then effectively 2000000 entities can be inserted per second?